# Did I "invoke a function" or "initiate a function" in computing?

Tags: verbs, writing-style, computing

According to Google, [***initiate***](https://www.google.co.za/search?espv=2&q=initiate+meaning&oq=initiate+meaning&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.156798.159345.0.159469.16.9.0.1.1.0.562.1518.2-1j2j0j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..11.5.1524.Rc36NflIdfw) means "cause (a process or action) to begin" and [***invoke***](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=invoke+meaning&oq=invoke&aqs=chrome.2.69i59l3j0l3.2064j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) means "cause (a procedure) to be carried out".

In computing, should I say, "I invoked a function" or "I initiated a function"?

Comment: **Invoking** a function is perfectly alright, when used in programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd argue that you do neither and instead *call* a function.(Because it's the commonly used term when discussing function usage in my experience.)

But to answer the question:
Initiating is usually associated with setting up properties of objects(or variables in general) when they are first created, so invoke seems the slightly more logical choice and in some frameworks there actually is an `Invoke` function to start methods.

Comment: I thought setting up properties of objects and variables was called _initializing._ Is there a distinction between the two terms?

Comment: @Heath: Sure, there is a difference: _initialize_ is defined as "assign initial values to something" in Wiktionary while _initiate_ means "to begin; to start". However in practice the two terms are used pretty much synonymous because this subtle distinction becomes only relevant if you have (for example) a big class with a large amount of members so that precise naming becomes paramount.

Comment: Invoke/call synonymous: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invoke+the+function%2C+invoked+the+function%2C+invoke+a+function%2C+invoked+a+function&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvoke%20the%20function%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvoked%20the%20function%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvoke%20a%20function%3B%2Cc0

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

Comment: I disagree. You call a *method* and invoke a function.

Comment: @Jim: What does that page mean when it says "a JavaScript function can be invoked without being called"? It can be invoked with () ?

Comment: @TimRomano- yeah I think that’s what they mean. But I don’t think of it that way.  I think of the parens as ***being*** the call/invocation.  The parens are what turns an anonymous declaration into a call rather than making it a “self-invoking” function.